# Reverse sort in ajaxsolr

Tags: jquery, sorting, solr

Using ajaxsolr and having browser compatibility sort issues. Thinking best shot is turning off solr sort and doing a client side control. Here's the code that creates the object array and my feeble attempt at reverse the sorting:

```
getFacetCountsMap: function (property) {
    var counts = [];
    for (var facet in this.manager.response.facet_counts[property] [this.field]) {
        counts.push({
            facet: facet,
            count:parseInt(this.manager.response.facet_counts[property][this.field][facet])
        });
    }
    return counts;
}
```

I replace 'return counts; with the following:

```
counts:counts.sort(function(a, b){
 return b.count-a.count;
  });
 return counts;
 },
```

No error message, but no sort either. Am I in the ballpark or not even in the game?

Answer (score 0):

You code may not work in IE

```
counts = counts.sort(function(a, b){
     return (b.count - a.count) >0 ? 1 : -1 ;
});
```

You had better use 1 & -1

Comment: sort order not reversed in either case:•Recipes (1)
•Image (2)
•Training material (39)
•Full text (532)
•Project data (1140)
•Citation (136675)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [facet.sort](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort) Solr parameter instead of doing this client side.